# SQL Query based on rules

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have some tables with following structure.

Table 1

```
s_cd        p_cd        c_cd        record
ABC         ALL         DEF         Comment-
ABC         ALL         GHI         Comment-
QWE         RTY         UIO         Comment
```

Table 2

```
type        title
AA          Ants
BB          Bees
CC          Cats
```

I'm looking for a solution that would yield an output based on a certain rule, that if Table 1 has a **p_cd** as **ALL**, then we need to fetch all **type** from Table 2 and append into *Comment-* and also replace **p_cd** for each **type**. If this sounds confusing, please look at the tables for better understanding.

```
s_cd        p_cd        c_cd        record
ABC         AA          DEF         Comment-AA
ABC         BB          DEF         Comment-BB
ABC         CC          DEF         Comment-CC
ABC         AA          GHI         Comment-AA
ABC         BB          GHI         Comment-BB
ABC         CC          GHI         Comment-CC
QWE         RTY         UIO         Comment
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database(s) you are really using.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the tags. I need a solution in MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the data in terms of two sets.

1st set is those that are "ALL", Second set is those that are ***NOT*** "ALL"

In the first set cross join to table2 (Return the combination of all records in table1 to all records in table2.  Since we know we want all records in table2 for each record in table1, then a cross join is what we need to generate the necessary data).  In the second set no cross join as we have all the needed information from the 1st table.

```
SELECT T1.S_CD, T2.Type as P_CD, T1.C_CD, concat(T1.Record, T2.Title) as Record
FROM Table 1 T1
CROSS JOIN Table2 T2
WHERE T1.P_CD = 'ALL'

UNION ALL

SELECT T1.S_CD, T1.P_CD, T1.C_CD, T1.Record
FROM Table 1 T1
WHERE T1.P_CD <> 'ALL'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH
-- input, don't use in final query
table_1(s_cd,p_cd,c_cd,record) AS (
          SELECT 'ABC','ALL','DEF','Comment-'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ABC','ALL','GHI','Comment-'
UNION ALL SELECT 'QWE','RTY','UIO','Comment'
)
,
table_2(type,title) AS (
          SELECT 'AA','Ants'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BB','Bees'
UNION ALL SELECT 'CC','Cats'
)
-- end of input
SELECT
  s_cd
, type AS p_cd
, c_cd
, record||type AS record
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON p_cd='ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM table_1
WHERE p_cd !='ALL'
ORDER BY 1
;
```

Comment: Does `||` work as a string concat operator in SQL server?  I know it works in Oracle, but I thought SQL Server was `+`

Comment: No; I had not seen it was SQL Server; use '+' instead of '||'.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Select Table1.s_cd,
    Case when Table2.type is not null then Table2.type else table1.p_cd end as p_cd, 
    Table1.c_cd, Case when Table1.p_cd='ALL' then Table1.record + table2.type else Table1.record end as record
    from Table1 left outer join Table2 on Table1.p_cd='All'
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how/why this would work.  It looks like it will but SQL answers alone are not as powerful as those that explain why it works.  I like the fact that it's not using a union but I don't like the fact that it hides a cross join in a left join with limited (missing) join criteria.